# Get Temporary Files Directory value from my extension

Tags: extension

In my extension I need to write a temporary .csv file but (it's my first extension) I'm not able to get the configured "Temporary Files Directory" value.
How can I do it?
Thanks

Marcello

Answer (score 2):

You can get any settings values from the API and, you can see how, exploring the API through http://yoursite.site/civicrm/api URL.

To answer your question you can follow this screenshot:

[image]

Comment: It's not clear for me (I'm a beginner in extensions) how to get the PHP code from your image.

Comment: You can generate this PHP code going to the civicrm/api URL on your site.